# How to make batch read certain parts of text and convert it into a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

so I'm just wondering if it's possible to to make a batch file read a line of text but split every letter up into it's own variable, ex:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p text=input:
set out=
set out2= 
set /p text=input: 

:loop
set out=%out% %text:~0,1%
set out2=%out2:~1% %text:~1%
set text=%text:~1%
if defined text goto loop
echo %out% -%out2%
pause
goto start
```

What I've written here doesn't work (I was just fiddling around trying to find the answer)
But what I was trying to do was to make "out" and "out2" into 2 separate values. Where "out" would be the first letter typed, and "out2" would be the second letter and so on. (planning to have about 16 out's that can read the first 16 letters of whatever the user inputs and make it into separate varibles)

ex: typing "ab" in the same line would result in "out" being "a" and "out2" being b

Another thing I couldn't figure out either was how to stop "out" from reading everything after the first letter. If anyone could help me with this issue, please explain what you've done to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Concerning your last paragraph: `set "out=%text:~0,1%"` extracts the first character (position index `0`, and length of `1` character) from the input text…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an easy solution which is way easier to understand (for me at least)

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
title Test
color a
mode 150

:start
cls
echo test
echo.
set /p text=Input: 
set pos=1

:Reader1
echo Val-%pos% = !text:~%pos%,1!
set c[%pos%]=!text:~%pos%,1!
set /a pos=%pos%+1
if "!text:~%pos%,1!" NEQ "" goto Reader1
pause
```

Comment: Your code does not work. If you enter `ABC` as the input, it will only output `B` and `C` in the echo statement and will only assign `B` and `C` to variables.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the `set pos=1` to `set pos=0`

Comment: Well I can tell you from 30 years of experience that fix will still cause you problems. But I will leave that to you to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little trick you can use with `CMD.exe` and the /U option. The `FOR /F` command is necessary to capture the output to assign to a variable. I then build a pseudo array with the `cnt` variable. The `SET out` command is just used to display all the variables in the pseudo array.

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET /P "text=INPUT:"
set "cnt=0"
for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('cmd /u /c "echo %text%"^|find /V ""') do (
    set /A cnt+=1
    CALL SET "out%%cnt%%=%%G"
)
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%cnt%) DO CALL echo %%out%%G%%
endlocal
pause
```

And here is just a quick run of the code.

```
C:\Users\Squashman\Desktop>so.bat
INPUT:foobar
out1=f
out2=o
out3=o
out4=b
out5=a
out6=r
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is the answer you provided but I fixed your logic errors.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
title Test
color a
mode 150

:start
cls
echo test
echo.
set /p text=Input:
set "texttmp=%text%"
set cnt=0

:Reader1
set /a cnt+=1
echo Val-%cnt% = !texttmp:~0,1!
set c[%cnt%]=!texttmp:~0,1!
set "texttmp=%texttmp:~1%"
if "%texttmp%" NEQ "" goto Reader1
```

Comment: It works great for the first couple of values, however it begins messing up in the higher numbers.

Comment: it starts "echoing" the wrong numbers when you use a lot of input letters. ex:
`out1=a
 out3=c
 out2=b`

Comment: @Gabrielnigme20, unfortunately I have no idea what that means in your mind.  You will need to provide a better description or show me what you are seeing.

Comment: My assumption @Squashman, is that `set out` will list `out*` variables alphabetically, meaning `%out10%`, `%out11%`, `%out12%`, `%out13%`, `%out14%`, `%out15%`, and `%out16%` will be output before `%out2%`, `%out3%`, `%out4%`, `%out5%`, `%out6%`, `%out7%`, `%out8%`, and `%out9%`. This of course would mean that [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780955/how-to-make-batch-read-certain-parts-of-text-and-convert-it-into-a-variable#comment114541218_64781403) showing `out1=a  out3=c  out2=b`, is incorrect, because that will not happen with your code.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct @Compo, that was what I meant. So how can you fix that?

Comment: `set out` is just a quick method of showing you the variables @Gabrielnigme20, and not part of your question. You should therefore use another method of showing you the variables, if you really need to display them like that. Alternatively, you could change `set "cnt=0"` to  `set "cnt=100"`, and change `CALL SET "out%%cnt%%=%%G"` to `CALL SET "out%%cnt:~-2%%=%%G"`

Comment: @Gabrielnigme20, just like every other console command, they are not numeric aware like Windows Explorer is. Everything is output in order per each character. The `FOR`, `DIR`, `FORFILES`, `SET`, etc, etc all output like that.

Comment: If you want to iterate the array, you can use a `FOR /L` command. `FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%cnt%) DO CALL echo %%out%%G%%`

Comment: @Gabrielnigme20, I have swapped out the `SET OUT` command with the `FOR /L` logic in my code.  I also took the liberty of fixing your code and have added that to my answer.